# How to add third party libraries to custom framework with CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I want to add third party libraries (like Swinject, or AlamoFire) to my custom framework (that created with swift) with CocoaPods.

the way I'm using is open terminal and navigate to my framework directory and run `pod init`. after that adding third party libraries to Podfile and then run `pod install`.

is this way correct for using my framework later in my app project? and is there a better way for doing this?

Comment: Try to be more precise and more specific. What do you mean by a custom framework? Did you build that framework by yourself? If your framework works without any issue then you can just add all other new frameworks in the pod file as a list and install them by `pod install` on your terminal.

Comment: Yes I mean my framework. after installing pods I added my framework to my project by this tutorial [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/17753301-creating-a-framework-for-ios#toc-anchor-006) but the problem is my app won't find third party libraries.

Comment: According to your link, It seems like you have added your custom framework to your project without any pod. If that's the case and then if you want to add other frameworks which need Pod, it supposes to work perfectly.  But just remember, In the future, if there's any update available, you have to handle the update separately. For custom integration and the pod one.

Comment: because it is first time for me to creating framework, I'm reading that tutorial to create a framework, but I realize that I need third party libraries for my framework, so I used CocoaPods to add third party libraries to my framework but my app won't find third party libraries that been used inside my framework.

Comment: and for those problems you said in the future (new updates available) what should I do? or how I must added third party libraries to my framework to prevent that problems you said?

Answer (score 0):

For installing the third-party libraries into the project:

**Step 1:** Open the terminal and navigate to the project directory.

**Step 2:** Type `pod init` in the terminal and press enter.

**Step 3:** Add the third-party libraries into the Podfile.

**Step 4:** Type `pod install` in the terminal and press enter.

Comment: Do you mean adding third party libraries to my app? or to my framework?

Comment: Actually, there are two ways to add third-party libraries: 1. Thought pods. 2. Thought Swift Package Manager. So, add third-party libraries to the app using pods and add third-party libraries to the framework using Swift package manager.

Comment: I didn't want to add third party libraries to my app, I want to add them with CocoaPods to my framework.

Comment: Try this, Your Project -> Target -> General -> Embedded Binaries and add the third-party libraries here.

Comment: I didn't want to add third party libraries to my app project, instead I want to add them to my framework.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to add **dependencies** in your Custom Pod **Podspec** -

```
s.dependency 'Alamofire', "~> 5.4"
s.dependency 'PromiseKit', "~> 5.4"
```

For further reference - [Cocopod Link](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html)